# Garbage Collection of PivotItems in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, garbage-collection, pivotitem

I have a Page with Pivot (mainPivot) and several PivotItems in it. If in some point I do

```
mainPivot.Items.Remove(pivotItem1);
```

or

```
mainPivot.Items.Clear();
```

Does this mean that children of mainPivot will be collected by GC and I will get possible exception when

```
mainPivot.Items.Add(pivotItem1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep a reference to `pivotItem1`, it won't be garbage collected. And you still have a reference, otherwise you wouldn't be able to add it back to `mainPivot`.